# Checking the sql statement being run from JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, average, jdbctemplate

I am trying to run a sql statment

```
select `key`, avg(score) from score group by `key`
```

to find the average score grouped by the column key. I am using JdbcTemplate to query with a mySQL db. Below is the line of java code

```
List<MarkupScore> scores = mysqlDbTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(MarkupScore.class));
```

The query works as planned in my db manager (picture below)

[image: Running query]

but when I try and access the List scores. I have a list of 3 MarkupScore which indicates the group by worked but the average scores are set to 0. I know my sql statement is not the problem since it works on the actual database. I think the problem is somewhere when the jdbctemplate translates the sql statement? I have also tried to run just

```
select avg(score) from score
```

and this too returns a 0. Does jdbctemplate not support average?

I have included a picture of the db that I am working with below

[image: datbase]

Comment: Post complete code for mysqlDbTemplate and MarkupScore classes, so we can look at them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're mapping the values with `BeanPropertyRowMapper`, it's trying to map a column named `avg(score)` to a similarly named property which doesn't exist. Give the `avg(score)` an alias (i.e. `avg(score) AS score`)  that maps to the correct property in `MarkupScore`.

And when asking a question, include *all* the necessary information.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly the issue! Sorry about not posting all the information. I wasn't sure how much of the code I should have posted and erred on the side of not having majority of the question being code.

Comment: Yea, it can be hard to know what the proper amount of code/info is.